# Sequelize increment function returning error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Trying to increment an integer field on a model instance in my DB. Here is the relevant code.

```
models.Options.findAll({
        where: { 
            PollId: poll_id, 
            name: option_to_update
        }
    }).then((option) => {
        option.increment('votes');
        res.json(option);
    });
```

When I console.log(option), it shows as an Instance so I know it inherits from the Instance class which has an increment function as can be seen here

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/3e5b8772ef75169685fc96024366bca9958fee63/lib/instance.js#L934

However, when I try to run option.increment, I get this back

> Unhandled rejection TypeError: option.increment is not a function

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What's the exact problem, though?

Comment: Sorry, I just re-read the question and realized I completely skipped over the error. The problem is that it returns option.increment is not a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findAll()` will return an array of results, so if you want to increment the field, you should use `option[0].increment('votes')` (assuming you want to update only the first result).

Or, if you know there's going to be at most one result,  you could use [`findOne`](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/model/#findoneoptions-promiseinstance) instead of `findAll`.

Because incrementing is done entirely server side, if you want to retrieve the current version of the document in the database after incrementing, you need to [reload](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/instance/#reload) the instance first.

I think this would be the appropriate way of doing that:

```
models.Options.findOne({
  where: { 
    PollId: poll_id, 
    name: option_to_update
  }
}).then(option => {
  return option.increment('votes'); // assumes `option` always exists
}).then(option => {
  return option.reload();
}).then(option => {
  res.json(option);
});
```

(of course, you could take a shortcut and assume that `votes` will be its current value + 1 after incrementing, but in a highly concurrent situation that might not always be the case)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I had another quick question, I'm not seeing the increment reflected when I res.json(option) right after incrementing it. Is that because the db needs to be synced to reflect the increment first?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a lot!