# Sequelize read data from create and decrement

Tags: mysql, sql, express, sequelize.js

As I've read in this article [Sequelize increment function returning error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44104860/sequelize-increment-function-returning-error)

I have done the next code:

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
models.sparepart_request.create({
    codWO: req.body.codWO,
    codSparePart: req.body.codSparePart,
    quantity: req.body.quantity,
    date_request: req.body.date_request,
    codUser: req.body.codUser,
    request_return: req.body.request_return,
    received: req.body.received
}).then(function (item) {
    return models.sparepart.decrement(
        'stock', {
            by: req.body.quantity,
            where: {
                codSparePart: req.body.codSparePart
            }
        }
    );
}).then(function (item) {
    res.status(200);
    res.json(({
        success: true,
        message: 'Query successful',
        data: item //This is null, I need the values from creating
    }));
}).catch(function (error) {
    logger.error(JSON.stringify(error));
    res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Query not successful and error has occured cretaing',
        error: error,
        stackError: error.stack
    });
    return res.status(500);
});
```

The problem is the following:

My JSON answer is the following:

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "Query successful",
"data": [
    [
        null,
        1
    ]
]
}
```

How can I take the value of the create item?

NOTE: I've tried to do a transaction but always return a error or stops and gives me a Time Out error. I don't know how to do a transaction with a instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
returning: true, // to get updated data back
```

To get result back from update , destroy and other function where it just returns the no of rows affected , like

```
return models.sparepart.decrement(
    'stock', {
        by: req.body.quantity,
        where: {
            codSparePart: req.body.codSparePart
        }
        returning: true, // to get updated data back
        plain: true, // for plain object and not raw data
    }
);
```